# error in execute sonar-runner command in windows 7

Tags: sonarqube

i want to analysis my java project with sonarqube and execute this command in windows console:

```
sonar-runner  -Dproject.home=D:\integ
rated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core
```

but i have error after execute command:

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknow
n': sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion, sonar.sources
```

Answer (score 1):

You must create a sonar-project.properties file in your project home directory. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner.

Comment: I am create sonar-project.properties in project home directory but i have this error